# Stack data (maybe pivot_longer) but complicated, R

Tags: r

I have data like this:

```
df<-structure(list(record_id = c(1, 2, 4), alcohol = c(1, 2, 1), 
ethnicity = c(1, 1, 1), bilateral_vs_unilateral = c(1, 2, 
2), fat_grafting = c(1, 1, 0), number_of_adm_sheets_used = c(1, 
NA, NA), number_of_adm_sheets_used_2 = c(1, 1, 1), number_of_fills = c(7, 
NA, NA), number_of_fills_2 = c(7, NA, 2), total_fill_volume_ml_left = c(240, 
NA, NA), total_volume_ml = c(240, 300, 550), implant_size_l = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), implant_size_l_2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

It is info about patients with each row representing a patient that underwent breast surgery.

I'd like to change it into each row representing a particular breast (of the two).  There are several variables, everything from 'number_of_adm_sheets_used' to 'implant_size_l_2' that have a column for each side.  I'd like to change those to represent either.  An example is 'number_of_adm_sheets_used' stood for on the left side, and 'number_of_adm_sheets_used_2' was on the right side.  I'd like to combine them to become one column of sheets used that was for either side.

My expected output would look like:

Pre-
[image]

Post-
[image]

I figure its some variant of pivot_longer but I'm having trouble with a few aspects:

- the real data has 68 columns
- I only need a duplicate row if the column "bilateral_vs_unilateral" is a "1" (meaning bilateral)
- The way I've used pivot_longer before, you'd say "cols" and pick a big range, I'm not sure how to stack pairs of columns,  if that makes sense.
- Luckily, despite having 68 other columns, all of the "trouble" columns are shown below.  Pairing 'number_of_adm_sheets_used' with 'number_of_adm_sheets_used_2'
  'number_of_fills' with 'number_of_fills_2'
  'total_fill_volume_ml_left' with 'total_volume_ml'
  and 'implant_size_1' with 'implant_size_1_2'

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility, if I'm understanding the issue correctly.

```
# Make long format
df.long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -record_id) %>%
  mutate(subject = ifelse(str_sub(name, -2, -1) == "_2", "breast 2", NA),
         name = str_remove(name, "_2")) %>%
  group_by(record_id, name) %>%
  mutate(subject = case_when(
    subject == "breast 2" ~ subject,
    n() == 2 ~ "breast 1",
    n() == 1 ~ "patient"
  )) %>%
  ungroup()

# statistics regarding the patient
patient <- df.long %>%
  filter(subject == "patient") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-subject)
# statistics regarding each breast
breasts <- df.long %>%
  filter(str_detect(subject, "breast")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

# merge the two data.frames
patient %>%
  inner_join(breasts) %>%
  select(record_id, subject, everything())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you rename your "trouble columns" to a consistent pattern, then you can use `pivot_longer()`'s `names_pattern` argument and `".value"` sentinel to pull pairs of values into rows. In my example code, I suffixed these with "_l" or "_r" for left- and right-sided variants. We can use the `values_drop_na` argument to keep only the valid rows for unilateral cases.

I also changed `alcohol` to a factor, just to demonstrate that it doesn't throw the error you noted in the bounty.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>% 
  mutate(alcohol = factor(alcohol)) %>% 
  rename(
    number_of_adm_sheets_used_l = number_of_adm_sheets_used,
    number_of_adm_sheets_used_r = number_of_adm_sheets_used_2,
    number_of_fills_l = number_of_fills,
    number_of_fills_r = number_of_fills_2,
    total_fill_volume_ml_l = total_fill_volume_ml_left,
    total_fill_volume_ml_r = total_volume_ml,
    implant_size_l = implant_size_l,
    implant_size_r = implant_size_l_2
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = ends_with(c("_l", "_r")),
    names_to = c(".value", "side"),
    names_pattern = "(.+)_(l|r)",
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  )
```

Output:

```
### move pivoted columns up front for illustration purposes
df_long %>% 
  relocate(record_id, side, number_of_adm_sheets_used:implant_size)

# A tibble: 4 x 10
  record_id side  number_of_adm_sheets_used number_of_fills total_fill_volume~
      <dbl> <chr>                     <dbl>           <dbl>              <dbl>
1         1 l                             1               7                240
2         1 r                             1               7                240
3         2 r                             1              NA                300
4         4 r                             1               2                550
# ... with 5 more variables: implant_size <dbl>, alcohol <fct>,
#   ethnicity <dbl>, bilateral_vs_unilateral <dbl>, fat_grafting <dbl>
```

Comment: This seems to work great!  You must have edited your code a second ago because I was about to comment that the fill volumes weren't getting combined but then you fixed it.  You also helped me understand my real data a bit better because I was wondering why not everbody got doubled and found a bunch of incomplete, missing data.  Will award bounty once it allows me

Comment: @JoeCrozier Glad it's working! Yes, at first I missed that `total_fill_volume_ml_left` was paired with `total_volume_ml` since the latter didn't have "fill" in the name, but then caught and fixed it.